# Float divs horzontally

Tags: css-float

I am trying to float divs horizontally, however its falling into a new line.

http://jsfiddle.net/nyCrY/4/

It works only if I set width of the #holder higher than its content.

Is there a way to do this without setting the fixed width on #holder?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you taken into account the box model: margins, border, padding, in your math?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really with pure CSS.

You can use a static width (which you don't want to do), you can use floats + whitespace (which is unreliable), or you can dynamically calculate the necessary width with javascript and set the style's width to that number.

According to this tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/

> I spent some time playing with the float property and the white-space
>   property to see if I could find a way to fight browser auto-wrapping,
>   but I didn't have much luck. Page elements which are floated but do
>   not have a width exhibit a property where they expand to the width of
>   the content inside them. I thought perhaps if I put a bunch of float
>   elements inside of that, it might just keep expanding beyond the width
>   of the browser window. No dice. There is also a white-space: nowrap;
>   property in CSS which I thought might be able to be exploited to fight
>   the auto-wrapping, but it only works for text elements, not blocks or
>   just any old thing you set to inline. Oh well.

So, he basically is saying, no its not possible with just css.

But he goes on to say that you can do some javascript magic to achieve it:

> JavaScript clearly has the ability to manipulate page elements and do
>   calculations on-the-fly.

Comment: My problem is that I want to apply horizontal jScrollPane to #holder. However if I set the width of #holder to the width of all content inside, then jScrollPane wont create any scrollbars. I believe width on #holder needs to be set to 100% for a scrollbar to appear, if I am not mistaken.